Sum of all elements of a $p$-section of a group
Let $G$ be a finite group. A $p$-section of $G$ is a subset of the form $S(x) = \{g \in G \mid g_p \text{ is conjugate to } x\}$, where $x$ is a $p$-element of $G$, with $p$ a prime, and $g_p$ denotes the $p$-part of the element $g$. It is easy to see that $p$-sections are the disjoint union of the $G$-conjugacy classes contained within them.
Exercise (5.5) in Navarro's "Characters and Blocks of Finite Groups" is to prove the following:

Let $U$ be a $p$-section of a finite group $G$ and let $e_{B_0}$ be the central primitive idempotent of $FG$, where $F$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$, associated to the principal block of $G$. Then, writing $\hat{U}$ for the sum of all elements of $U$, $\hat{U} \in e_{B_0} Z(FG)$.

For this, he suggests using the previous exercise, (5.4), which goes as follows:

Let $U$ be a $p$-section of a finite group $G$ and let $f_B = \sum_{\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(B)} e_\chi$, where $B$ is a block of $G$ and the $e_\chi$ are the central primitive idempotents of $\mathbb{C}G$ associated to $\chi$. Then, $\hat{U}$ is a linear combination of the conjugacy classes of $G$ contained in $U$.

For some context, we can take $F = R/M$, where $R$ is the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{C}$ and $M$ is a maximal ideal containing $pR$. Then, we get a map $*: R \to F$, the natural projection. It is known by this point in the book that $(f_B)^* = e_B$, for a block $B$ of $G$. This makes it clear that the two exercises are very closely related, and I initially thought that the former would be a simple corollary of the latter.
I have been able to solve the second exercise, given in the hint, but I have no idea how to use it for the former. To be more precise, the fact that this holds only for the principal block means that the character $1_G$ will have to be used at some point, but I can't really see how, since all the computations that started appearing included sums of all the characters in $B_0$, meaning the distinguished role of $1_G$ hasn't appeared.
Here is one of my (many) attempts:
Write $\hat{U} = \sum \hat{L}$, where the sum runs over all the conjugacy classes of $G$ contained in $U$. Then, by the hint, we know $\hat{U}f_{B_0} = \sum a_L \hat{L}$. In particular, going to $FG$, $\hat{U} e_{B_0} = \sum (a_L)^* \hat{L}$. It is easy to see that $\hat{U} \in e_{B_0} Z(FG)$ if and only if $\hat{U}e_{B_0} = \hat{U}$. Hence, we have to show that $(a_L)^* = 1$ in the field $F$.
Some computations done to prove the hint show that $$a_L = \sum_{K} \frac{|K|}{|G|} \left(\sum_{\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(B_0)} \chi(x_K)\overline{\chi(x_L)}\right)$$
where $x_K \in K$, $x_L \in L$, and the first sum runs over all the conjugacy classes of $G$ contained in $U$. Here is where I get stuck, as I don't know anything that can be done to this coefficient to prove the desired result...
Does anyone have a hint of how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!
